# AngularJS Directive - Template Select Not Updating Ng-Model

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

I have two directives in my module.  The first is from https://github.com/banafederico/angularjs-country-select.  I used it as a model for the second.  The two directives represent input fields, but the second one is not storing a value.  The link function is not updating the ng-model value.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    if (!!attrs.ngModel) {
        var assignDivision = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign;

        elem.bind('change', function(e) {
            assignDivision(elem.val());
        });

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(division) {
            elem.val(division);
        });
    }
}
```

In my ide (netbeans) the 2nd (dependent) drop-down does not display the selected value in the drop-down or update the model.  In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/676mp/), the display updates, but the model does not.  I am unsure how to update the value of the model to the selected value.

Comment: Have you considered [select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) for such hierarchical selects?

Comment: I don't think it will be a good fit in this particular case.  Thank you for providing this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because in the second directive you defined `scope: {...}` when passing in the country value.  This creates an isolate scope in the directive and thus ng-model on the element doesn't really work, you need to create a two way binding to the parent variable in the directive's new isolate scope

http://jsfiddle.net/676mp/2/

```
scope: {
    country: '@',
    myDivision: '=division'
}
```

And then in the HTML

```
<division-select division="myDivision" country="{{myCountry}}"></division-select>
```

**EDIT**: Also note that in the fiddle I changed your template for the directive to include its own `ng-model` for its own scope

Comment: Thank you so much.  This project has been a thorn in my side for too long.